# Замена последнего вохождения в строке в dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Как заменить последнее вхождение в каждой строчке dataframe,
строка имеет вид ADVA.SFP/2G5U/D1549.32U/SM/LC#D20.SFP
Надо заменить первую `'.'` и последнюю `'.'`. Точку в центре надо оставить.
Первую точку заменил на `'$'` -

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_excel('Stock_base.xlsx', sep=';', encoding='cp1251')
file['Pos'] = file['pos'].str.replace('.', '$', 1)
```

Comment: Укажите в вопросе строку, которую вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: Большое спасибо, оба метода работают.
Метод с regular expression сложный для меня т.к. пока плохо в них разбираюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы избавиться от точки в конце, сначала можно использовать метод [`rsplit()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html#pandas.Series.str.rsplit) с ограничением количества разделений до 1. И потом объединить с помощью [`join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html#pandas.Series.str.join), используя нужный вам разделитель.

```
file['Pos'] = file['pos'].str.replace('.', '$', 1).str.rsplit('.', 1).str.join('$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
                                     Pos
0  ADVA.SFP/2G5U/D1549.32U/SM/LC#D20.SFP
1                    aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee

In [14]: df['Pos'] = df['Pos'].str.replace(r'^([^.]*)\.(.*)\.([^.]*)', r'\1$\2$\3')

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
                                     Pos
0  ADVA$SFP/2G5U/D1549.32U/SM/LC#D20$SFP
1                    aaa$bbb.ccc.ddd$eee
```

PS [разбор Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/Qfm061/1)